# Creating a nested dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bigger code from which I obtain some datetime object for some events (YYYY-MM-DD) for two years (2021,2022) out of which I want to group data together in a nested dictionary structure. For a particular event, I want the following structure -

```
event_name:
   {2021:
      {01:
         number_of_datetime_having_month january,
       02:
         number_of_datetime_having_month_feb
       ...etc etc upto december},
    2022:
      {01:
         number_of_datetime_having_month_january,
       ........etc etc upto december}
    }
```

I am planning to write this data to csv and plot this afterwards.
I am wondering what will be the best approach. Hard-coding the schema beforehand?

Comment: it would be helpful to know what form you get the data in. it seems like the total number of datapoints is 24, right? just one per month for two years?

Comment: For example, all total I have two data points, lets suppose - one is `datetime.datetime(2022,2,4,0,0) and datetime.datetime(2022,2,11,0,0)` .  Then the final output should be `{2021:{01:0,02:0,........},2022:{01:0,02:2,03:0,.........}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetimes = [datetime.now() + timedelta(days=20*i) for i in range(20)]

# Sparse result (zero-counts excluded):

result = {}
for dt in datetimes:
    months_data = result.setdefault(dt.year, {})
    months_data[dt.month] = months_data.setdefault(dt.month, 0) + 1

# Non-sparse result:

result = {}
for y in set(o.year for o in datetimes):
    result[y] = {}
    for m in range(1,13):
        result[y][m] = 0
        
for dt in datetimes:
    result[dt.year][dt.month] += 1

# Output result
from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

Sparse output:

```
{2022: {9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 2},
 2023: {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2}}
```

Non-sparse output:

```
{2022: {1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
        7: 0,
        8: 0,
        9: 1,
        10: 2,
        11: 1,
        12: 2},
 2023: {1: 1,
        2: 2,
        3: 1,
        4: 2,
        5: 1,
        6: 2,
        7: 1,
        8: 2,
        9: 2,
        10: 0,
        11: 0,
        12: 0}}
```

Comment: Very useful, however I am not looking for sparse data. It should show month entry all the way up tp 12. So that all entries in my CSV are populated even though it might be zero.

Comment: @mrin9san answer updated

Comment: Brilliant ! simple and elegant. I did it too but with different approach. Posted as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the earlier answer of kwiknik (the sparse one), however i have to admit his approach is more elegant. Neverthless, I am posting my approach too.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetimes = [datetime.now() + timedelta(days=20*i) for i in range(20)]
result = {}
for dt in datetimes:
    months_data = result.setdefault(dt.year, {})
    months_data[dt.month] = months_data.setdefault(dt.month, 0) + 1 
############################################################################       
count=0
for year in result.keys():
    for k in range(1,13,1):
        for items in result[year].keys():
            if items==k:
                pass
            else:
                count=count+1 
        if count==len(result[year].keys()):
            result[year][k]='0'
        count=0  
        kk= dict(sorted(result[year].items()))
        result[year]=kk
print(result)
```

Output

```
{2022: {1: '0', 2: '0', 3: '0', 4: '0', 5: '0', 6: '0', 7: '0', 8: '0', 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 1, 12: 2}, 2023: {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: '0', 12: '0'}}
```